# How to make onsenui button bar item become checked on mousedown rather than click

Tags: html, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am currently using a button navigation bar from OnsenUI used to navigate through pages.  One thing that I want to change is how it selects a different button based on a click event instead of a mousedown event (See the JSFiddler link I posted at the bottom).  I want to change it because the mouse-down event is typically more responsive to user interaction than the click event.  The code below is what I am currently using for my navigation bar:

```
        <div class="navigation-bar">
        <div class="navigation-bar__center">
            <div class="button-bar" style="width:200px;margin:7px 50px;">
                <div class="button-bar__item">
                    <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a" ng-mousedown="resCtrl.tabIndex = 1;" checked>
                    <div class="button-bar__button">Search Criteria</div>
                </div>

                <div class="button-bar__item">
                    <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a"  ng-mousedown="resCtrl.tabIndex = 2;">
                    <div class="button-bar__button">Search Results</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The ng-mousedown event in the code above does change the resCtrl.tabIndex variable, but it obviously doesn't  change which button-bar__item is checked in the GUI due to the click event.  How do I fix this?

By the way, here is a JFiddler page for the button bar:

http://jsfiddle.net/5frafqtw/1/

Comment: I don't understand your question. I copy and paste your code in your JsFiddle and it works fine.

Comment: Here it works. http://jsfiddle.net/5frafqtw/13/